# How to convert RTMP stream to RTSP Stream

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, rtmp

I'm trying to process an RTMP stream using OpenCV in Python. Unfortunately, OpenCV doesn't support RTMP. I want to do video processing in real-time so converting to a `*.mp4` or the like isn't an option.

Is there an `ffmpeg` command to convert RTMP to RTSP? Is there a better way to process the RTMP stream with Python?